# Getting ember data to adjust URL per model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The majority of my models follow the standard naming convention that Ember Data expects. I offset all requests with:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

But otherwise pretty standard. The exception comes in when I have an API structure like what I have around units of measure. In this case I have three related endpoints: `uoms`, `uom-systems`, and `uom-contexts`.

The way that they are referenced is (using GET for example purposes, same applies to other CRUD operations):

- GET /uoms
- GET /uoms/systems
- GET /uoms/contexts

How do I tell Ember Data in these situations to look in the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with a little digging around I came up with an answer to my own question. And good news ... it's quite easy to do. All you need to do is create a custom adaptor which does two things:

1. Offsets the namespace appropriately (in my example that means `api/uoms`)
2. Shorten/rename the target model name (in my example `uomSystems` needs to be `systems`)

Here's the code:

```
App.UomSystemAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/uoms',
    pathForType: function(type) {
        // gets rid of leading "uom" and pluralizes like normal
        return Ember.String.pluralize(type).substr(3); 
    }
});
```

This example could be repeated with no code changes needed for the UomContext model. Not sure if there is a way to do a single custom adaptor for both; that would seem more graceful but this solution is simple and works for the one-off scenarios I'm trying to address.